# How to represent the state of this system after the measurement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, observables, quantum-states, quantum-measurements

This is a question my professor gave us in the test.

Consider the spin-$\frac{1}{2}$. Alice measured the system along the $z$ direction, and she observed the outcome as $+1$.

After Alice's measurement, Bob measured the system again along the direction $\vec{n} = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0)$. The corresponding matrix representation of the corresponding operator is $$
\sigma_{n} = \vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma} = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & e^{-i\phi}\\
e^{i\phi} & 0
\end{matrix}\right).
$$
Bob found that the system aligned along $+\vec{n}$. Then, what is the quantum state of the system after Bob's measurement? It is sufficient to represent the quantum state as a column vector under the basis of $|u\rangle$ (along the $+z$ direction) and $|d\rangle$ (along the $-z$ direction).

The above is the body of the question. When I was trying to solve it, I was confused about how to calculate the state using the information I have already known. After Alice's measurement, the state is $\left(\begin{matrix}1\\0\end{matrix}\right)$, but does this affect the outcoming state after the Bob's measurement? If it does, how?

Comment: The true answer is that after this procedure you have an entangled state between Alice, Bob, and the spin-$\tfrac12$ qubit. Your professor probably wants you to give the "simplified" answer that ignores the different terms in the total state but only keeps the one which Bob observed. This conceals the coomplete picture, so it is not a particularly good homework exercise. Just be diplomatic in answering!

Comment: @JosBergervoet Why do you say the procedure yields an entangled state? It rather yields a separable product state.

Comment: This is a bit like a homework exercise so I'm not writing a complete answer. Use your knowledge of basic ideas about measurement. What physical observable is being measured by Bob? What is the (hermitian) operator representing that physical observable? If a given eigenvalue is obtained by measurement, the system state becomes the corresponding eigenstate of the operator.

Comment: @Tobias Fünke.  See my answer below for why I think the complete answer requires a 
 more complicated treatment (and may require description as an entangled state).

Comment: I don't have much time right now, sorry. But I'd have read the question as starting from some arbitrary bipartite state and then computing the post-measurement state (after both measurements), which would here always be unentangled (and always the same, irrespective of the initial bipartite state as long as the measurement outcomes are not prohibited).

Comment: @Tobias The question *fails to specify* who is going to use the qubit and with how much knowledge. After both measurements, use of the qubit by Alice, whitout knowkledge of Bob's result, would give her a mixed state (the qubit maximally entangled wit Bob). And in any case there *will be* an entangled total state after the procedure, I don't see how you want to avoid that!

Comment: Oh, you are right, the question is not clear. I've misread it, it seems.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question and not a "do my homework for me" question.

Comment: Write the eigenvector that has eigenvalue +1 for Bob's $\sigma_n$. Write it in terms of the $u$ and $d$ states. That will be your answer. The reason that is your answer is because Bob's measurement simply projects out the part of the initial state that is along Bob's eigenvector with eigenvalue +1 (because that is the value Bob measured).

Answer (score 4):

After measuring a quantum system, it is in the eigenstate corresponding to that measurement, period.

Alice's measurement might affect how likely Bob's outcome is, but once Bob's measurement has been performed, it fully determines the state of the system.

Answer (score 1):

> Alice measured the system along the $z$ direction, and she observed the outcome as $+1$...
>
> ...Bob measured the system again along the direction $\vec{n} = (\cos\phi,\sin\phi,0)$. The corresponding matrix representation of the corresponding operator is $$
> \sigma_{n} = \vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma} = 
> \left(\begin{matrix}
> 0 & e^{-i\phi}\\
> e^{i\phi} & 0
> \end{matrix}\right).
> $$
> Bob found that the system aligned along $+\vec{n}$. Then, what is the quantum state of the system after Bob's measurement?

Use [the standard rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#State_change_due_to_measurement) for an ideal measurement. I will [apply the rule to the state ket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse#Collapse), but it can also be applied to the density matrix. (See, for example, bullet point 3 on page 1 of [these lecture notes](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs191/fa14/lectures/lecture89.pdf). See also, Eq. (2.93) in Nielsen and Chuang's "Quantum Computation and Quantum Information," which is the same as the equation on bullet point 3 of the linked lecture notes.)

Given that Bob's initial state (the state after Alice's measurement) is $|u\rangle$, the state after Bob's measurement has to be the normalized projection onto Bob's measurement eigenstates with the correct eigenvalues. In the current case it is a fairly trivial projection since there is only one eigenstate to consider. (Bob's state space is two-dimensional and his sub-space of vectors with value +1 is a one-dimensional space--in more complicated systems with degenerate eigenvalues the projection might have to be onto multiple states, but in your case there is only one eigenvector to consider.)

You just need to write down the eigenvector of your $\sigma_n$ matrix that has eigenvalue $+1$. I'll leave it to you to do that explicitly, and I'll denote that state by $|+n\rangle$.

The relevant projection operator associated with Bob's measurement is:
$$
\hat P_{+n} = |+n\rangle\langle +n|\;.
$$

Per the problem specification, the initial state (prior to Bob's measurement) is $|u\rangle$.

Thus, the standard rule tells us that the state **after** Bob's measurement is:
$$
|\psi_{after}\rangle = \frac{|+n\rangle\langle+n|u\rangle}{|\langle+n|u\rangle|}\;,
$$
where the "initial" state is $|u\rangle$, since we know that Alice just previously measured +1 along the z-axis. (This happens to not really matter for this particular problem, but you should understand the general rule.)

Since the $|u\rangle$ state has a non-zero overlap with the $|+n\rangle$ state, and since the phase does not matter, the state after the measurement can be written more simply as:
$$
|\psi_{after}\rangle =|+n\rangle\;.
$$

> It is sufficient to represent the quantum state as a column vector under the basis of $|u\rangle$ (along the $+z$ direction) and $|d\rangle$ (along the $-z$ direction).

Yes. That sounds fine. Write $|+n\rangle$ in terms of the $|u\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$ states. This is seemingly part of what your teacher wants you to do... along with understanding that the measurement just projects out the eigenstate corresponding to the measured eigenvalue.

Answer (score -4):

The question about "the quantum state of the system" without further specification can only be honestly answered by describing
the entire system.
The other question, whether representation "as a column vector" (along the $+z$ direction) would suffice, really depends on how the qubit is subsequently used, and by whom, which is not specified clearly enough  in the description you have!

With a qubit $|\psi\rangle_q$ starting as:
$$\alpha\ |1_z\rangle_{\rm q} +\beta\ |0_z\rangle_{\rm q} \tag{1},$$
Alice's measurement leads to
$$\alpha\ |1\rangle_A\ |1_z\rangle_{\rm q} + \beta\ |0\rangle_A\ |0_z\rangle_{\rm q}
\tag{2a},$$
where Alice now is entangled with the qubit state, because of what she has seen she can be in two states and the qubit has acted as the "control qubit" (see for instance the working of the CNOT gate in quantum computing).

We just rewrite this in the basis of
$n$-direction eigenvectors $(e^{-i\varphi}, 1)$ and $(1,-e^{i\varphi})$, just for Bob's convenience. The expression, completely identical to $(2a)$, then looks like:
$$\alpha\ |1\rangle_A\big(\frac{{\large e^{i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}} |1_n\rangle+ 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |0_n\rangle\big)_{\rm q} +
 \beta\ |0\rangle_A\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|1_n\rangle-\frac{{\large e^{-i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}}|0_n\rangle\big)_{\rm q} \tag{2b}$$

Now Bob does his measurement, again the qubit acts as the control qubit, $|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ will put Bob in state $|0\rangle_B$, while $|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ puts him in state $|1\rangle_B$. So we just replace $|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ with $|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}$
and  $|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ with $|1\rangle_B|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ everywhere. The result:

$$\begin{align}
& \frac{{\alpha\large e^{i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}} 
   |1\rangle_A|1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
+ \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle_A|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}
\\ & \qquad  \qquad  
+ \frac{\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\ |0\rangle_A|1\rangle_B|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
- \frac{{\beta \large e^{-i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle_A|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q} \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

So we see: entanglement between $3$ subsystems. Can we simplify that?!
Let's look at three scenarios for the sequel:

1. Alice now gets back the qubit but she doesn't know what Bob's measurement result was. Let's suppose that
   her own $z$-direction measurement result was $+1$. If she wants to describe the system now, she can throw away the
   terms with $|0\rangle_A$ because that is not the state she is in ("subjective collapse of the wave function" is allowed here!) but after that she still has, after renormalizing:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   & \frac{{\large e^{i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}} 
      |1\rangle_A|1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
    + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle_A|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q} =
   \\ & \qquad \qquad = 
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ |1\rangle_A \ \big(  e^{i\varphi} 
       |1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
    +   |0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}\big).  \tag{4.1a} 
   \end{align}
   $$
   She can leave out the common factor $|1\rangle_A$ because she knows she is in that state, but the remaining part is still a mixed state, of a qubit maximally entangled with Bob:
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ \big(\  e^{i\varphi} 
       |1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
    +   |0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}\ \big).  \tag{4.1b} 
   \end{align}
   $$
   To  use the qubit, she must describe it as a density matrix,
   $$
     \rho_{\rm q} = \begin{pmatrix}
       \frac12 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac12 
   \end{pmatrix}                        \tag{4.1c}
   $$
   which in this case is a scalar matrix independent of the chosen basis, because of the equal-magnitude coefficients in the Schmidt decomposition $(4.1b)$.
2. If Alice is *also* told what Bob has measured
   (let's assume he measured $+1$ along the $n$-direction) then she can leave out
   the term with $|0\rangle_B$ and write the state as:
   $$ e^{i\varphi} 
      |1\rangle_A|1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}  \tag{4.2a} 
   $$
   She can also leave out any reference to the known states and even the phase factor (which is probably lost in the procedure anyway), writing just the qubit:
   $$ 
    |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
     =  \frac{{1}}{\sqrt{2}}\ \big(\ e^{-i\varphi}\ |1_z\rangle
    +  |0_z\rangle\ \big)_{\rm q}        \tag{4.2b}
   $$
3. If Bob keeps the qubit, he can immediately leave out the terms that
   are not what he observed. If, for instance, he measured $+1$ that leads of course to:
   (after renormalizing)

$$ {\alpha\ e^{i\varphi}}\ 
   |1\rangle_A|1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
+ \beta\ |0\rangle_A|1\rangle_B|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}  \tag{4.3a}
$$
And in this case the state is fully separable into states for the three subsystems, factoring as:

$$ \big( {\alpha\ e^{i\varphi}}\ 
   |1\rangle + \beta\ |0\rangle\big)_A \ \ |1\rangle_B \ |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
  \tag{4.3b}
$$
So Bob can describe it without reference to Alice, and can of course also leave out his own know state, so for the qubit he simply has:
$$ 
 |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}    \tag{4.3c}
$$

Probably case 3) is what the question (silently) was referring to. But anyhow, an important notion is that in all three cases the rest of the universe does still exist, and can be included in a more complete description. Unless you believe everything else vanishes suddenly, the collapse of the wave function is merely a tool for computational efficiency. And in case 1) we see that the other subsystems will at least play a role in determining the kind of description you end up with.

Comment: Is there anything incomplete in just saying that the quantum state is $|1_n\rangle$ after Bob's measurement? Measuring the system after Bob's measurement will yield $1_n$ with complete certainty. Alice's lack of knowledge of the system is not a quantum phenomenon, and does not change the fact that the system is in the objectively definite state $|1_n\rangle$.

Comment: @Codename 47, That is totally incomplete and unphysical. The time evolution of QM cannot create that state. Instead there is always a superposition of Bob having measured $+1$ and Bob having measured $-1$, so in the combined state that gives terms with $|1\rangle_B|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}$ and $|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}$. Also it doesn't help to say that something "is not a quantum phenomenon" since *everything* must have a description in QM, unless you think that QM is incorrect...

Comment: QM is not limited to unitary time evolution when measurement is involved, unless you take the concept of a measurement only having one outcome as being nonsensical. In that case, I recommend you amend your answer to state that clearly from the start, seeing as the question states "Bob found the system aligned along $+\vec{n}$", thus assuming a single outcome of the measurement. 

In any case, the question can be restated as "assuming Bob is in state $|1\rangle_B$, what is the state of the qubit?" In which case your answer is also $|1_n\rangle_q$.

Comment: On that last statement we can agree, but you are wrong earlier: I do not have to deem "having one outcome as being nonsensical" to get my solution. The proof that there should be just one term left in the outcome is on you, give us the time evolution that you propose! Write down the altered differential equations for wave functions in space and time. It'll be very interesting to see whether there is a sudden jump, or a gradual change, and propagating with a finite speed or instantaneously. You claim it "is not limited to unitary time evolution", so what time evolution do you propose?

Comment: The comment section is not for extended discussion - let us keep this about clarifying the answer. There are plenty of resources on quantum measurement out there if you are interested, you could for example start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_in_quantum_mechanics#State_change_due_to_measurement).

Comment: This **is** about clarifying the answer! Non of those proposals does give a time evolution that *objectively* makes the disputed terms in the total system solution zero, so that is why in the answer I pointed out that only *for some purposes* you can ignore those terms and that this "subjective collapse of the wave function" is allowed here. And I made clear at the start that the answer to "the quantum state of the system" should simply have all the terms. So hopefully everything is clarified now!

Comment: @JosBergervoet OP's question is about a *single* qubit that is measured twice. It is a pedagogical problem to teach OP about how sequential measurements change the state of the system. There is only one qubit, so there can be no entanglement. OP is already confused enough without trying to inject superfluous/unnecessary concepts into the problem.

Comment: No @hft, for a question asked on SE, OP deserves a full answer and no "shut up and calculate" way to sweep things under the carpet (we are not on-demand homework solvers!)
The professor here apparently tries to enforce the "objective collapse" idea on the students. That is only possible in extended QM theories like the CLS model, GRW model, or DP model, that actually give collapsing time evolution of the state. But that would go outside mainstream QM theory! Surely not pedagogically the right thing to do.
So I just follow mainstream unitary QM, *and* explain subjective collapse.

Comment: @JosBergervoet Why do you get to dictate the norms of the Physics Stack Exchange? OP doesn't "deserve" anything more than an answer to the question that OP posed (if that). Every member of this community reads and responds to the question as they see fit. Clearly, your answer is the least favorable thus far, so why do you think you should be the one to explain to others how best to answer?

Comment: @JosBergervoet According to your norms, any answer that treats a hydrogen atom as a single-particle in a potential field is "wrong" since the "full" system includes two dynamical quantum particles, not a single dynamical electron... And further, there are even more dynamical particles to discuss in the "full answer" since the hydrogen nucleus is made of quarks and gluon. So, a "full answer" to a student's question about hydrogen orbitals seemingly must leverage the entirety of Quantum Electrodynamics as well as Quantum Chromodynamics (according to your theory of "full" answers).

Comment: We digress, @hft. You claim (above) "so there can be no entanglement", I claim the final state is entangled:
$\frac{{\large \alpha e^{i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}}|1\rangle_A|1\rangle_B |1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
+\frac{\large \alpha}{\sqrt{2}} |1\rangle_A|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}
+\frac{\large \beta}{\sqrt{2}}\ |0\rangle_A|1\rangle_B|1_n\rangle_{\rm q}
-\frac{{\large \beta e^{-i\varphi}}}{\sqrt{2}}|0\rangle_A|0\rangle_B|0_n\rangle_{\rm q}$, or else you need altered theories, plagued with problems: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-collapse_theory#Problems_and_criticisms_to_collapse_theories